# MVVM How to pass object in Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

Is there any way to bind whole object while generating list by itemscontrol?
MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
   private List<TrackModel> _trackModels=new List<TrackModel>();

    public List<TrackModel> TrackModels
    {
        get { return _trackModels; }
        set { _trackModels = value; }
    }
```

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrackModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding TrackModel}"/> <!--Here should be my UserControl-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The thing is that I want to create my own UserControl that will receive TrackModel instance because I will need it to get FileName of track to play music. Is there any way to pass TRACKMODEL to my UserControl while using ItemsControl?

Comment: "Is there any way to pass TRACKMODEL to my UserControl while using ItemsControl?" - ItemsControl does that. it this case ItemTemplate is a template for TRACKMODEL. and you can explicitly say so by setting DataType: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mynamespace:TrackModel}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need more than

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrackModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:YourUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

or an automatically applied DataTemplate somewhere in a ResourceDictionary, like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TrackModel}">
        <local:YourUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrackModels}" />
```

It requires that `YourUserControl` does not explicitly set its own `DataContext` property, but instead simply binds its child elements to the automatically provided DataContext object, which is a `TrackModel` element from the `TrackModels` collection.

Answer (score -1):

There is another option if you wanted to explore it though it maps to the same property.

If you give your ItemsControl an x:Name property such as myitems you will be able to access the ItemsSource property from the code behind and set the content there.

Comment: This has however nothing to do with what was asked for, i.e. how to use a UserControl in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Actually the question was "Is there any way to bind whole object while generating list by itemscontrol? MainWindowViewModel.cs"
And there are most definitely two options. The XAML one you showcased and the second "code behind" method I mentioned.

Comment: That is a misconception. The question was about the UserControl in the ItemTemplate: "*my own UserControl that will receive TrackModel instance*". It is irrelevant whether you bind the ItemsSource in XAML or set it in code behind.

Answer (score -2):

For any1 other looking for answer. Well, the answer is quite simple as I find out.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TrackModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}"/> we just type ,,Binding" without anything else
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: How does this solve your problem of having your UserControl to display a TrackModel item?

Comment: in ViewModel you can make property of type TrackModel and in userControl just bind to it

Comment: But there is no UserControl, just a Label. The answer does not make sense, except when there is another, implicit DataTemplate with something like `DataType="{x:Type local:TrackModel}"` that contains a declaration of the UserControl. This would however make the explicit ItemTemplate redundant.